# filter list using Java 8 lambda or stream api

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

**My class structure -**

```
class A {
    List<B> bList;
}

class B {
   List<C> cList;
}
```

Now i have a list of class A and i want to filter it based on condition that c.size() > 0. I can filter it using 2 for loop one for list A and other for list B but i want to know can i filter list of A using java stream api without for loop.

**My current code (updated code) -**

```
List<A> result = = new ArrayList<>();
for (A a : aList) {
   List<B> tempBList = = new ArrayList<>();
   for (B b : a.getBList) {
       if (b.getCList.size() > 0) {
          tempBList.add(b);
       }
   }

   if (tempBList.size() > 0) {
       a.setBList(tempBList);
       result.add(a);
   }
}
```

Comment: you probably forgot to put a `break;` statement after the `result.add(a);` in your example

Comment: @lino There's nothing to break. He needs to collect all the `A` instances that matches the given predicate. Don't add spurious comments like this.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala currently he adds an `a` instance for every `b` that matches the condition `b.c.size() > 0`. Which looks like a typo to me

Comment: @Lino No, that is not a typo, that is what he needs. He used public fields instead of getters.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I think we talk next to each other. `a.b` is a `List`. OP iterates over that list. and then checks if an item `b` has a list `b.c` which is bigger than 0. If yes add `a` to the result. The current code does this for every `b`. Which means that possibly multiple same `a` instances are in the result list

Comment: @lino makes sense. In that case break is needed.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala that's what I am trying to say ;)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can:

```
List<A> result =
    listOfA.stream()
           .filter(a -> a.b.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.c.size() > 0))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming you want to add each instance of `A` that passes that filter to the output `List` once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. items is the list which you want to filter.

```
    List<A> result = new ArrayList<>();

    result = items.stream().filter(a -> a.b.stream().filter(b -> b.c.size() > 0).count() > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Interesting idea to use `count()`. But keep in mind that `filter(..).count(..) > 0` will go through the whole stream of `A`s. Using `anyMatch()` will yield in the same result, but will stop as soon as it finds one `A` with `C`s already, which makes it more efficient.